# Javascript to remove an object from an array if one element in the object contains a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, object

I have an array of objects such as:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "attachment_text": "Support: hello there! I need some help syncing records",
            "ticket_text": "Ticket 1537 from ronburgundy@news.com"
        },
        {
            "attachment_text": "Copied from original request - 401 unathorized",
            "ticket_text": "Ticket 1459 from klaus.kinsky@kinsky.com"
        },
        {
            "attachment_text": "Contact request form received",
            "ticket_text": "Ticket 1173 from sophia@copolla.com"
        },
        {
            "attachment_text": "Hello, we need to troubleshoot some problems",
            "ticket_text": "Ticket 1591 from pat@pending.com"
        },
        {
            "attachment_text": "Contact request form received",
            "ticket_text": "Ticket 1483 from bugs@bunny.com"
        },
        {
            "attachment_text": "Contact request form received",
            "ticket_text": "Ticket 1393 from elmer@fudd.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

What javascript can I use to remove any objects where the **attachment_text** field contains the string "Contact request"?

Preferably pure javascript (i.e. not a library such as lodash)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Simple `.filter()` would do the trick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the filter method of Array Objects in JavaScript. I have created a demo for you below:

```js
var data = {
  "value": [{
      "attachment_text": "Support: hello there! I need some help syncing records",
      "ticket_text": "Ticket 1537 from ronburgundy@news.com"
    },
    {
      "attachment_text": "Copied from original request - 401 unathorized",
      "ticket_text": "Ticket 1459 from klaus.kinsky@kinsky.com"
    },
    {
      "attachment_text": "Contact request form received",
      "ticket_text": "Ticket 1173 from sophia@copolla.com"
    },
    {
      "attachment_text": "Hello, we need to troubleshoot some problems",
      "ticket_text": "Ticket 1591 from pat@pending.com"
    },
    {
      "attachment_text": "Contact request form received",
      "ticket_text": "Ticket 1483 from bugs@bunny.com"
    },
    {
      "attachment_text": "Contact request form received",
      "ticket_text": "Ticket 1393 from elmer@fudd.com"
    }
  ]
}

const result = data.value.filter((data) => !data["attachment_text"].includes("Contact request"))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `filter` method, which will keep each item where a specific condition results to `true`.
In your case, the condition can be a simple `includes` method to check for the presence of the **"Contact request"** string.

```
var d = {
  "value": [
    {
      "attachment_text": "Support: hello there! I need some help syncing records",
      "ticket_text": "Ticket 1537 from ronburgundy@news.com"
    },
    {
      "attachment_text": "Copied from original request - 401 unathorized",
      "ticket_text": "Ticket 1459 from klaus.kinsky@kinsky.com"
    },
    {
      "attachment_text": "Contact request form received",
      "ticket_text": "Ticket 1173 from sophia@copolla.com"
    },
    {
      "attachment_text": "Hello, we need to troubleshoot some problems",
      "ticket_text": "Ticket 1591 from pat@pending.com"
    },
    {
      "attachment_text": "Contact request form received",
      "ticket_text": "Ticket 1483 from bugs@bunny.com"
    },
    {
      "attachment_text": "Contact request form received",
      "ticket_text": "Ticket 1393 from elmer@fudd.com"
    }
  ]
}

// result contains what you desires
var result = d.value.filter((d) => !d["attachment_text"].includes("Contact request"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
value.filter(x=>x.attachment_text.indexOf('Contact request') > -1);
```

The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.

This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.

and works fine perfectly with every browser.